# Document Circulation logbook

Tags: vocabulary

Is "circulation log" a correct word for record of internal exchange of documents between divisions of an organization?

Comment: I can't answer this, because what a specific name of a internal system is called in *your* company may be different to what it is called in my company. If the term will only be used internally, you can name it whatever you choose.  However if it an external auditing requirement, then you name it whatever the auditors choose to call it.

Comment: However "circulation of documents" is understood and records are often recorded in a log book or log.

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside any  arbitrary naming requirements that will have nothing to do with the English language *per se*, yes, *circulation log* is a suitable name for a record of who has removed documents from a repository in an organization.

The phrase **in circulation** is commonly used in libraries to refer to books that are available to be taken out of the library by patrons. This would be an analogous usage.